# How to redirect to profile page with id user paramater?

Tags: django

I want redirect to user profile after click "Profile" dropdown. But profile need id user, I don't know to link

## views.py

```
def profile(request, user_id):
    #Something....
    return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

## urls.py

```
path('profile/<int:user_id>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
```

## profile.html

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url ???? %}">Profile</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In django current user id is in `request.user.id` so you have to pass this to the url as an argument in order to get what you wanted. So try provide this in your template like below:

```html
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'profile' request.user.id %}">Profile</a>
```